# React Native Soundboard App To Run On IOS and Android without App Store/ Google Play

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have altered a small Github project in order to have a soundboard app for a bachelor party. I'd like to install this on the guests phones. I have tried it in Expo Snack and it works, but I'm not sure how to build and deploy it to have it as an app 'locally' that can be downloaded. Could you please help me?

Download from Expo Snack and install the app on IOS and Android.

Comment: Never used Expo snack, 10 seconds looking around the UI: Click on "Run on device" -> "QR Code", done.

Comment: Yes, but that would require using the internet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For using the app in release build, you'd need to build the APK and download it on the android device.
For iOS, you'd need to build the release version in archive, and send the `.ipa` file to the iPhone you want to install the app on.

**Note: If you are installing the `.ipa` file through a link, you'd need to do it on Safari browser**

Now if you are using a bare `react-native` project, you'd need to have a KeyStore for android.

You can generate it using this command

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then move it inside of the `/android/app/` directory, set up the key alias, password  inside of `gradle.properties` file and run `./gradlew assembleRelease` inside of `android/` directory.

Then you could just install the APK on your android device and you would be able to run the app normally.

Check out [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) for the complete documentation and steps to do it.

However, for Expo, you can either eject your project, which would make it as a bare `react-native` project and add native files to your project.

Or you could use `eas` in order to build APKs for the app.
Check out [Expo's docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/) for the complete steps.

As for iOS check out [this tutorial](https://yuvsinha01.medium.com/install-and-share-ipa-file-on-ios-without-using-testflight-7a8709a6ceb5) as it shows you how to do it.